# How to ignore time while checking date using before(Date d)

Tags: java, date

I know alternate methods to check next date but I would like to know is there any possibility of ignoring checking time when using before.

I have the following code

```
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
          int dayOfMonth) {
      try {
      if (fired == true) {
          return;
      } else {
          // first time fired
          fired = true;
      }
      String date = checkDigit(monthOfYear + 1) + "/"
              + checkDigit(dayOfMonth) + "/" + year;
      strDate = date;
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        Date d=df.parse(strDate);
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if(d.before(cal.getTime()))
        {
             etDOB.setText(strDate);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Enter Valid Date Of Birth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             etDOB.setText(" ");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

d.before(cal.getTime()) checking date but if the selected Date is next Date than it also checking time
```

Example :
Date value selected is `feb 24 2013` so d contains the same

```
cal.getTime() also contains feb 24 2013
```

but the first date having the time `00:00:00 GMT+5:30` and second has the time `1:00:00 GMT+5:30` this cause the condition to fail. So my question is  how do Ignore before to check time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format and parse the date from `cal.getTime()` using `df` (`SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")`) which will get rid of time and then compare the result with `d`.

Answer (score 3):

While createing the Calendar Object

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.Minute, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.Second, 0);
```

now your condition will not fail