# Need to validate if the return date is greater than the Departure date?

Tags: android, validation, date

I've two date pickers which go into two seperate edit text boxes. One is the depart date and the other is the return date. I need a validation theory that will make sure that the return date has to be after the departure date..

Thanks for the help

Here is my code :

```
    DepartDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
            ReturnDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

public void selectDate(View view) { // Function used to set the date 
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton1: // Using the first image button to call the first date picker. 
            DialogFragment newFragment1 = new SelectDateFragment(0); // Giving an index to the date picker so it won't overwrite the textfields
            newFragment1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            break;

        case R.id.imageButton2:  // Using the first image button to call the first date picker.
            DialogFragment newFragment2 = new SelectDateFragment(1); // Giving an index to the date picker so it won't overwrite the textfields
            newFragment2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            break;
        }

    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) { // Setting the format of the date and setting where the selected date will be entered to 
        DepartDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        DepartDate.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year); //Setting the format in which the date will be shown in the textview

    }

    public void populateSetDate1(int year1, int month1, int day1) {

        ReturnDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ReturnDate.setText(month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1);

    }

    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        int type;
        public SelectDateFragment(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            if(type == 0) { //If the first date picker was clicked then call the following function
                populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
            } else if(type == 1) { //If the second date picker was clicked then call the following function
                populateSetDate1(yy, mm + 1, dd);
            }
        }
```

I also have a button with an onClickListener. I will be hoping to make the button unclickable if the return date is greater than the depart date.

Comment: You can try something like this, As I have posted in thsi question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038015/how-to-ignore-time-while-checking-date-using-beforedate-d

Answer (score 1):

I have used this class that you can use as an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string dateToCompareToFieldName)
    {
        DateToCompareToFieldName = dateToCompareToFieldName;
    }

    private string DateToCompareToFieldName { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {


        DateTime earlierDate = (DateTime)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(DateToCompareToFieldName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);


        if ((DateTime)value != null)
        {
            DateTime? laterDate = (DateTime)value;
            if (earlierDate <= laterDate)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult("End date must be later than start date!");
            }

        }
        else {return new ValidationResult("End date is expected.");}


    }
}
```

You can then use this as an annotation for your datefields.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this question here:
[Date Comparison using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811121/date-comparison-using-java)

but you can also set the button to be not enabled if the dates don't pass your validation.

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
if(!passesValidation) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below java code. I hope it will help to you.

```
public class ValidateDate{

  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;

  private static final String PATTERN_OF_DATE = 
          "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";

  public ValidateDate(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_OF_DATE);
  }

    public boolean DateValidate(final String date){

     matcher = pattern.matcher(date);

     if(matcher.matches()){

     matcher.reset();

     if(matcher.find()){

             String dayIs = matcher.group(1);
         String monthIs = matcher.group(2);
         int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));

         if (dayIs.equals("31") && 
          (monthIs.equals("4") || monthIs .equals("6") || monthIs.equals("9") ||
                  monthIs.equals("11") || monthIs.equals("04") || monthIs .equals("06") ||
                  monthIs.equals("09"))) {
            return false; // only 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 has 31 days
         } else if (monthIs.equals("2") || monthIs.equals("02")) {
                  //leap year
          if(year % 4==0){
              if(dayIs.equals("30") || dayIs.equals("31")){
                  return false;
              }else{
                  return true;
              }
          }else{
                 if(dayIs.equals("29")||dayIs.equals("30")||dayIs.equals("31")){
                  return false;
                 }else{
                  return true;
              }
          }
          }else{                 
        return true;                 
          }
       }else{
              return false;
       }          
     }else{
      return false;
     }              
   }
}
```